# When referring to an author, should I use their pseudonym or their real name?

Tags: names, books

When referring to an author, such as in a book report or essay, should I use their pseudonym or their real name when I am speaking about them or their works? Thanks!

Comment: What does the publisher say? Or are you their autobiographer? I guess it depends on the context.

Comment: To me, it seems that this is more of a question about cultural and literary conventions for using names, than about English per se. If you have a book report or essay to write, you should have a teacher or editor who can give you advice about matters like these.

Comment: Nobody refers to Mark Twain as Sam Clemens, or George Orwell as Eric Blair, or O. Henry as whatever the hell his real name was. Same for Saki, George Eliot, George Sand, etc., and so on, ad infinitum.

Comment: "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet" - from Shakespeare's play Romeo and Juliet.  Seriously though: You are writing the essay. What do you want to say? Why? What is the purpose of the essay? If you know then the answer is obvious - do what is relevant. If you don't know then how are we supposed to know?

Comment: Use their pseudonym.  That's how the book is listed at the library and that's what the author wanted when he or she wrote the book.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Are you sure about this idea?  So you're saying it doesn't matter what we call the author?  Being an author that has used a pseudonym before, I would not at all be happy if people tried to use my "real" name.  My real name is what I gave you not what you think it should be.

Comment: @michael_timofeev - It depends entirely what the purpose of the essay is. It may be historical, it may be an expose. The name may be irrelevant, or highly important.  Without any context why should we know any better than the person asking the question?   I don't mind helping people but I object to doing their thinking for them.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I know.  I've just always wondered why critics refer to an author by their given name and not the one they publish under.  I give you plus one for referencing the Bard.  Any reference to him in an answer is cool.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I think we've both seen articles that start "X, whose real name was Y..."  I think, what's the purpose of exposing their real name?  Doesn't add anything.  If anything it makes the author seem like one of those people who go to a magic show and guess out loud at the method, which is as ignorant as going to a play and shouting, "it's not real, you know.  Her name isn't Juliet but Anne Hathaway."

Comment: @michael_timofeev - That's why I quoted Shakespeare. I don't give a damn about whether names are real 90% of the time. However it can be important - for example when a woman wrote under a man's name at a time when female authors were not taken seriously.  My sole reason for commenting was that it's a pointless question.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'm not so sure it's a pointless question.  Although if I were writing a "scholarly" article about Alice in Wonderland, I would use Carol and not Dodgson.  The op said book report, which sounds like high school...or O levels (is that how its referred to in the UK?)

Comment: @Robusto William Sydney Porter.

Comment: I agree with @chaslyfromUK:  it depends on the topic and purpose.  It's *Mark Twain* for discussing Tom Sawyer and Huckleberry Finn.  It should probably be Samuel Clemens for discussing his career as a lecturer and stand-up comedian of his day.  And for gawd's sake, don't write articles like the one in Wikipedia that say "Twain was born shortly after a visit by Halley's Comet."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the pseudonym is a better choice, out of respect to the author, and other names can be dealt with separately.

e.g. You don't refer to Lewis Carroll as Charles Lutwidge Dodgson when talking about Alice in Wonderland, wouldn't you?

Neither would you refer to Lemony Snicket as Daniel Handler when referring to A Series of Unfortunate Events, etc.

But if they wrote different work under different names, then you would bring up the other names if it is worthy to mention so.

ex. The Cuckoo's Calling was written by J. K. Rowling, under the pseudonym of Robert Galbraith.

Or in general, "X wrote (some work written under another name) under the pseudonym/alias/whatever of Y."

Comment: Perhaps change "always" to something less absolute.  I agree with your answer, btw.